# C# Draw a horizontal line on each stacked column chart

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

Currently I need to develop a tool with chart as the major component. Chart control is also new for me. I have do a lot of reading, researching to learn and understand the whole picture of the chart control.

After all, I had stuck and question on how to draw a horizontal line (blue & red horizontal line) on stacked column chart as image shown below:

[image: This is the requirement for my project]

Here what I have done so far:

[image: My charting tool project]

This is my code so far:

```
            // X-Axis labels settings
        chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Angle = -45;
        chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 1;

        // Y-Axis labels settings
        //chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = 100;
        chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = 95;

        // Plotting chart
        using (YieldEntities context = new YieldEntities())
        {

            // Extract yield loss list
            var yeilds = (
                from yeild in context.YeildDatas
                group yeild by new { yeild.Loss } into newyeild
                select new
                {
                    Loss = newyeild.Key.Loss,
                    Percentage = newyeild.Sum(p => p.Percentage)
                }).OrderByDescending(p => p.Percentage);

            //context.YeildDatas.Select(p => new { p.Loss, Percentage = p }).Distinct();

            // Create new series
            foreach (var yield in yeilds)
            {
                chart.Series.Add(yield.Loss);
                chart.Series[yield.Loss].ChartType = SeriesChartType.StackedColumn100;
            }

            // Label settings for first series
            chart.Series[0].SmartLabelStyle.Enabled = false;
            chart.Series[0].LabelAngle = -90;
            chart.Series[0].Font = new Font(Font.FontFamily, 15, FontStyle.Bold);
            chart.Series[0].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;

            var query = context.YeildDatas.ToList();
            foreach (var item in query)
            {
                DataPoint dp = new DataPoint();
                dp.SetValueXY(item.DateString, item.Percentage);
                chart.Series[item.Loss].Points.Add(dp);
            }

            // Set empty datapoint for each series
            foreach (var yield in yeilds)
            {
                DataPoint nulldp = new DataPoint();
                nulldp.SetValueXY("", 0);
                chart.Series[yield.Loss].Points.Insert(1, nulldp);
                chart.Series[yield.Loss].Points.Insert(6, nulldp);
                chart.Series[yield.Loss].Points.Insert(11, nulldp);
            }

            chart.Legends["Legend"].IsEquallySpacedItems = true;
            chart.Legends["Legend"].IsTextAutoFit = true;

        }
```

I hope to get any expert to guide me to solve this problem.

Comment: Are you drawing your charting control by yourself ? Or are you using finished chart control ? If you are using finish chart control, then try to use event Paint on chart control and try to DrawLine there

Comment: i'm using provided chart control in Visual Studio 2015. How to draw the line sir?

Comment: Your question is essentially a set of requirements. Any code to show?

Comment: I just need to draw the horizontal line/marker/goal (red & blue line) on top of each stacked column.

Comment: In addition to actually drawing you may also consider adding LineAnnotations or adding a Series of Charttype.Line for the same effect.

Comment: Thanks Taw. I will try the LineAnnotations. But for Line Chart, i tried to play with it but later it thrown an exception to me. I'll really appreciate if you can show me some example how to do that (if possible, show me the line annotations too ^_^) In advance, thanks for your kindness.....

Comment: @TaW: Thanks for give me LineAnnotation idea. Seems it work very well. I also implement the use of TextAnnotation as well to put the percentage on the line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is only sample, you can start from there:

```
// Data point to pixel
var pixelX = this.chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ValueToPixelPosition(dataPointX);
var pixelY = this.chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.ValueToPixelPosition(dataPointY);

// Pixel to data point
var dataPointX = this.chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.PixelPositionToValue(pixelX);
var dataPointY = this.chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.PixelPositionToValue(pixelY);

// Use event Paint to draw your line
private void chart1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
  // Convert dataPoint to pixel
  var dataPointX = this.chart1.Series[0].Points[0].XValue;
  var dataPointY = this.chart1.Series[0].Points[0].YValues[0];

  var pixelX = this.chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ValueToPixelPosition(dataPointX);
  var pixelY = this.chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.ValueToPixelPosition(dataPointY);

  // Only sample, pen should be initialized outside Paint method
  Pen pen = new Pen(Brushes.Red);

  // Example of drawing line with width=100 pixel
  e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, pixelX, pixelY, pixelX + 100, pixelY);  
}
```

Comment: x... how if I want to get width between 1st and 2nd data point? The return result I will use to replace the '100' as the width of the line.

Comment: Just convert dataPointX2 to pixelX2, and dataPointX1 to pixelX1, then pixelX2 - pixelX1 is the width

Comment: like this?

var dataPointX2 = this.chart.Series[0].Points[2].XValue;
Console.WriteLine(dataPointX2 );

why i try to figure out the value behind it return 0?

Comment: I dont know, what's your data look like. It was just a little help. You must play with it and figure it by yourself. It just math. Get pixel here, get pixel there. Substraction, addition,.... The above sample "100" is just a dummy. You cannot "just replace 100". It will not works.